# find if a tag exists by name in XMl using Java Dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, tags

How can I check if a specific child dose not exist in XML using Java Dom in the following sample: I am looking for all `userFiled` occurrences and in the first part, there are none. So I want to say if there is no tag `userField` do something.

```
<element class="AufOrgKombination" hash="AOK_1416092142370_76">
    <field name="layer">4</field>
    <field name="name">Function organisation unit combination 1</field>
    <field name="description"/>
</element>
<element class="AufOrgKombination" hash="AOK_1417643334024_77">
    <field name="layer">4</field>
    <field name="name">Function organisation unit combination 1</field>
    <field name="description"/>
    <userField hash="USERFIELD_1415779871581_0">3.0</userField>
    <userField hash="USERFIELD_1415779871581_0">N.A.</userField>
</element>
```

something like:

```
NodeList NodeuserField = element.getElementsByTagName("userField");
Element line;

for (int j = 0, l = NodeuserField.getLength(); j < l; j++) {
    line = (Element) NodeuserField.item(j);
    for (Entry<String, String> userFieldUserDef : map_userField.entrySet()) {
        if (element.getElementsByTagName("hash") == null) {
                                //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760109/finding-node-values-dom-with-in-java) I suggest using XPath again. You can do it via the Java XPath API (which sucks), or again use [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Yes, I'm affiliated with this project). There are several possibilities to determine via XPath if an element exist. You could just try to read it and test if the result is null. Here as an alternative: Declaring directly a boolean projection method:

```
public class ElementExists {

    public interface Projection {

        interface Element {
            @XBRead("./@hash")
            String getHash();

            @XBRead("count(./userField)>0")
            boolean hasUserField();
        }

        @XBRead("//element")
        List<Element> getElements();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Projection projection = new XBProjector().io().url("resource://data.xml").read(Projection.class);
        for (Projection.Element e : projection.getElements()) {
            System.out.print("Element with hash '" + e.getHash() + "' has ");
            System.out.println((e.hasUserField() ? "" : "no ") + "user field");
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints out

```
Element with hash 'AOK_1416092142370_76' has no user field
Element with hash 'AOK_1417643334024_77' has user field
```

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you can use the `java.util.Optional` type as return type and avoid the null check.