# Check if multiple XML tags exists using Java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I am trying to read a **XML document using Java.** I want to check if all the **tags exist** before trying to get the content in it.

I have something like this;

```
String ToolVersion;

if (element.getElementsByTagName("ToolVersion").getLength() > 0) {
                    ToolVersion = element.getElementsByTagName("ToolVersion").item(0).getTextContent(); }
```

I have over 20 XML tags, is there a way to do this **without having 20 "IF" conditions ?**

Comment: Foreach (Tag in tagList: tags) { if [retrive tag].getLenght>0;} i mean, create a tag list and then loop in.

Comment: this link may be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868212/find-if-a-tag-exists-by-name-in-xml-using-java-dom

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a schema validator? Writing your own code to do validation by hand seems a bit low-tech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code to think about.

```
String getData(Element e, String tagName){
    if (e.getElementsByTagName(tagName).getLength() > 0) {
        return e.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent(); 
    } else return null;
}


BODY

List<String> elementsList = Arrays.asList("ToolVersion", "ToolName", "SomethingElse");
Element e;
String tagData;

for(String tagName : elementsList){
    tagData = getData(e, tagName);
    //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [jaxb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). It provides marshaller and demarshaller which will help you in verifying whether tags exist or not.